# How to stop activity resizing/pushing up on keyboard open in dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, window-soft-input-mode

I have an activity, which should react on keyboard opening, so in the manifest, it has an attribute

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also, this activity can start a dialog, which has EditText. When it starts dialog, keyboard is shown, dialog (which is ok) and activity (not ok) are pushed up. It looks ugly and I want disable pushing of the activity up when dialog is visible.

Is there any beautiful way to solve this problem? 
Currently I am changing `softInputMode`at runtime, it works but it's annoying.

Also why the hell scrollview scroll not working with adjustPan?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `adjustPan` instead of `adjustResize`.

Comment: This one line could have been a comment.

Comment: I using this for dialog and it work like a charm!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Firstly,

remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` do not even change it from runtime.

Secondly, use `<NestedScrollView>` and add an attribute to it called:

`isScrollContainer="true"`

Try it and update here if it is exactly how you need.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your activity tag on manifest:

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```